# IIS static content compression not working

Tags: iis, compression

I try to make static content compression work for IIS but it's not working. I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard, and IIS 8.5.9600.16384.

I installed both static and dynamic content compression, and as you can see both are checked:

[image]

Also I went to configuration editor, and there I can see that JavaScript should be compressed:

[image]

But still I get no `Content-Encoding` HTTP header field in my response. What should I do?

Comment: Please read what failed request tracing says. One example is https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amb/2016/05/23/iis-respects-minfilesizeforcomp-for-static-compression/

Answer (score 2):

Could you get dynamic compression work when you deploy a simple webform application in new IIS site?

As Lex said, Enable Failed request tracing would be the best way to troubleshooting this issue.

1.Install failed request tracing in add role and feature->Web Server->health and diagnostics->tracing

2.Open IIS manager->go to your site node->failed request tracing->add..->all content->status code 200->ensure WWW Server/compression has been checked->finish.

3.Edite site tracing->Enable

4.Open log file in C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\W3SVC and check dynamic compression procedure.

[image]
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/06/15/lab-4-install-and-configure-failed-request-tracing/

Comment: Thank you so much. I got `NO_COMPRESSION_PROXY` as the reason for `DYNAMIC_COMPRESSION_NOT_SUCCESS `. Any idea what does that mean?

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli Hi No_Compression_proxy means HTTP request contains a Via header which means the request is relayed via a proxy server and system.webServer/httpCompression/noCompressionforProxies has set to true. You could try to set this value to false.

Comment: I actually checked the HTTP request/response via Fiddler and there was no `Via` header available. I moved to a CDN. Shame on Microsoft for these small stupid frustrations.

Comment: @mohammadrostamisiahgeli What about the configuration system.webServer/httpCompression/noCompressionforProxies have you tried to set it to false?

Comment: No, I didn't check anything else. This is so frustrating that I chose to completely ignore it and move to a CDN. Again, shame on Microsoft of its web server.